How to create ne record for container in cosmos db?
Strted to figuring out how to work with cosmos db with my side project.
And can not understand how i'm able to create a new record for container.
I have soem generic repository method, that invokers by controller:
public async Task CreateAsync(TEntity entity, string partitionKey)
    {
        
var itemResponse = await _container.CreateItemAsync<TEntity>(entity, new                PartitionKey(partitionKey));
        entity.Id = itemResponse.ActivityId;
    }

Controller:
[HttpPost("language")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLanguage(Language language)
{
    await languageRepository.CreateAsync(language, "language");
    return Ok();
}

The language contrainer has the partition key -> /language.
Now i just wanted to test my service via postman:
{
    "Language": "Spanish",
    "Name": "Spanish",
    "LanguageImage": ""
}

Model:
public class Language : Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("language_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("language_image")]
    public string LanguageImage { get; set; }

    public Language() : base(true)
    {
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ttl")]
    public int Ttl { get; set; }

    public Entity(bool generateId = true)
    {
        SetDefaultTimeToLive();

        if (generateId)
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }

    public virtual void SetDefaultTimeToLive()
    {
        Ttl = -1;
    }
}


After sending the query, receing error message: PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header.
I've tried to add partitionkey in headers, as params and also to json, but still receinving the same error.

When storing content, you should not provide the name of your partition key; rather, you should provide the value of the partition key.

So do you have a set of JSON documents with a "language" property that you are storing in Cosmos DB? And you want it to partition to different storage based on that "language" property?
If yes, you might look at this question:
PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header on CreateItemAsync
Otherwise, maybe explain a little more context what type of Cosmos DB are you using? Maybe share the full post body?
---Edit---
With the more details provided my guess is you just need to match your property name with the partition. So either always use "language_name" or always use "language". Just a guess!
